# How to randomise upper/lower case of a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, methods, character

I want to transform `'abcdef'` into `'aBCdeF'` or `'AbCDEF'` or any other random combination of lower and upper case characters. I need to use this with any given string. I am aware of `String`'s `#upcase`, `#swapcase`, `#capitalize` etc., but I don't think there is a built-in method for doing what I want. The best I came up with is something like:

```
'abcdef'.chars.map { |c| c.send [:upcase, :downcase][rand 2] }.join
```

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like this, where `x` is your string:

```
x.chars.map { |c| (rand 2) == 0 ? c.downcase : c.upcase }.join
```

The `map` method takes a block that randomly generates `0` or `1` for each char. If `0`, the char is returned as is, otherwise it gets upper-cased.

Comment: This is nice, but this will only work with a range of characters. I need this to work with any given string. `'abcdef'` was just an example.

Comment: Easy enough to fix, just updated answer, essentially the same, still just enumerates over an enumerable object.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer because it only upcases on a random basis... It never downcases, so a string like "FOO" would never be changed. The answer of @sawa does not have this problem.

Comment: A little modification to this method will make it execute a bit faster: ```x.upcase.chars.map { |c| (rand 2) == 0 ? c.downcase : c }.join```.  We're upcasing everything and then randomly downcasing.

Answer (score 5):

```
'abcdef'.gsub(/./){|s| s.send(%i[upcase downcase].sample)}
# => "aBCdEf"
```

Comment: Doesn't this come with the risk that the string might end up unchanged?

Comment: @Tom, its not truly random if the string cannot possibly return unchanged is it?